# How can I resolve "An error occurred while running subprocess ng" when deploying ionic app?

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I recently made an ionic app and when I try to deploy it using

```
ionic cordova build android
```

I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: [BABEL] C:\Users\dipes\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\demoapp\www\focus-visible-15ada7f7-js-es2015.js: Could not find plugin "proposal-numeric-separator". Ensure there is an entry in ./available-plugins.js for it. (While processing: "C:\\Users\\dipes\\OneDrive\\Documents\\GitHub\\demoapp\\node_modules\\@babel\\preset-env\\lib\\index.js")
See "C:\Users\dipes\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-8Jt401\angular-errors.log" for further details.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.
```

And in the log file, I get

```
    [error] Error: [BABEL] C:\Users\dipes\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\demoapp\www\focus-visible-15ada7f7-js-es2015.js: Could not find plugin "proposal-numeric-separator". Ensure there is an entry in ./available-plugins.js for it. (While processing: "C:\\Users\\dipes\\OneDrive\\Documents\\GitHub\\demoapp\\node_modules\\@babel\\preset-env\\lib\\index.js")
    at getPlugin (C:\Users\dipes\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\demoapp\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js:67:11)
    at C:\Users\dipes\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\demoapp\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js:258:62
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\dipes\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\demoapp\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js:258:43
    at C:\Users\dipes\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\demoapp\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:19:12
    at C:\Users\dipes\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\demoapp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:179:14
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dipes\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\demoapp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\gensync-utils\async.js:26:3)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Users\dipes\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\demoapp\node_modules\gensync\index.js:254:32)
    at evaluateAsync (C:\Users\dipes\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\demoapp\node_modules\gensync\index.js:284:5)
    at Function.errback (C:\Users\dipes\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\demoapp\node_modules\gensync\index.js:108:7)
    at errback (C:\Users\dipes\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\demoapp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\gensync-utils\async.js:70:18)
    at async (C:\Users\dipes\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\demoapp\node_modules\gensync\index.js:183:31)
    at onFirstPause (C:\Users\dipes\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\demoapp\node_modules\gensync\index.js:209:13)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: are you certain you have added this plugin to your project? cordova plugin add proposal-numeric-separator ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this file

[dir_project_name]/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/**ngcc_lock_file**